# how to call recyclerview multiple times in fragment

Tags: android-layout

> 

---

- Heading

  ## #

How to call recyclerview multiple times in fragment

Answer (score -1):

Its simple.

Just mention recyclerview in layout and in java class initialise it and pass array in it. 
thats fine.

Comment: Nonsensical answer to a nonsensical question.